# Mouse cursor dissappearing/flickering when not moving (Xubuntu 12.04 / xfce 4.10)

Tags: 12.04, xubuntu, mouse, xfce, cursor

Installed Xubuntu 12.04 with xfce 4.10 on ThinkPad E540.

When freshly booted, the mouse cursor works for about few minutes, 
then it starts to flicker and finally completely disappears, 
when not moving the mouse.

If I move around some folder (press/hold left mouse button) the cursor works ok.

Very annoying problem, any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try two things, pop into XFCE Settings -> Window Manager Tweaks -> Settings Tab and UNTICK Enable Compositing to turn of fancy desktop effects, this may help your cursor...

or...  Try using a newer version of Ubuntu with better hardware support for your graphics and bug fixes that may sort out the mouse flicker...  Note: 14.04 LTS will be out in April if you want to wait for another long-term release...

Comment: Wow! Your first approach worked perfectly. I just unticked "enable display compositing" and now the cursor works fine. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I installed CAELinux using the Ubuntu 12.04 and had the same problem.

I just installed "BLEACHBIT" and ran the entire utility. Now the dissapearing/Flickering cursor problem is resolved along with some much needed performance issues. Go figure.